# Selenium - how to reliably click on text?

Tags: python, html, selenium, web, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to click on text links and that does not work:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://my.gumtree.com/login")
driver.find_element_by_name("username").send_keys(email)
driver.find_element_by_id("existingUser").click()
driver.find_element_by_id("fld-password").send_keys(password)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Continue')]").click() # works

driver.get("https://my.gumtree.com/postad")
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[text()='For Sale']")[-1].click() # this now works, thanks
# driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@span,'Appliances']").click() # this worked but I need the next line instead
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[text()[normalize-space()='Phones, Mobile Phones & Telecoms']]").click() # this does not work
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[text()[normalize-space()='Phones, Mobile Phones &amp; Telecoms']]").click() # this does not work either
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[text()[normalize-space()='Mobile Phones']]").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[text()[normalize-space()='Other']]").click()
```

HTML:

```
<li class="border-b is-parent" data-category-name="Appliances" data-category-url="kitchen-appliances" data-category-id="2485" data-category-children="true">
  <span class="category-name">
    <span class="category-list-control is-parent">
    </span>
    Appliances
  </span>
</li>
```

What do I do wrong?

Comment: HTML code for any one of link?

Comment: <span class="btn-indent-icn icn-tag txt-orphan-from-m">
::before
</span>
<span>For Sale</span>

Comment: try like this //span[contains(text(),'For Sale')]

Comment: t worked for first item 'For Sale', thanks. But it did not work for other ones: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//span[contains(text(),'Appliances')]"}

Comment: I answered with a different kind of xpath to your problem. Try it!

Comment: No, it does not work I am afraid: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//span[text()[contains(.,'Appliances')]]"}

Comment: Try: `//span[contains(normalize-space(string()), 'Appliances')]`

Answer (score 4):

Try the below one. Hope it helps.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[text()='For Sale']")
```

Comment: It worked for first item 'For Sale', thanks. But it did not work for other ones: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[text()='Appliances']"}

Answer (score 2):

As per provided HTML code I hope it will work:

```
 //span[contains(text(),'For Sale')]
```

Comment: It worked for first item 'For Sale', thanks. But it did not work for other ones:  selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//span[contains(text(),'Appliances')]"}

Answer (score 1):

In Selenium the XPath finding it's a bit broken for recursive searches of elements that don't specify the tag name. So don't use: `//*[]`.

Furthermore the XPath is a bit broken. In your examples you are searching for an element that has an attribute named "`span`" that contains the whatever string.

It should look like this:

`driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(string(.),'For Sale']").click()`

If you want, you can try [germanium](https://github.com/germaniumhq/germanium), a free test framework that I wrote, that deals with this kind of inconsistencies and more. In germanium the same code looks like:

`click(Text("Other Home Appliances"))`

Comment: It worked for first item 'For Sale', thanks. But it did not work for other ones: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[contains(string(.),'Appliances')]"}

Comment: You try to select a LI element using an A tag :).

Try: `//li[contains(string(), 'Appliances')]`

Or Germanium: `Element("li", contains_text="Appliances").element()`

Comment: A last "sales" pitch, in Germanium there is a selector that searches using JavaScript, so you can just write: `Text("Appliances").element()` without having to care about the element type.

Answer (score 0):

Your provided HTML does not show that the Appliances span contains a lot of whitespace which is likely the reason you are not finding this element. Try the following Xpath to find the Appliances span,

```
//span[text()[normalize-space()='Appliances']]
```

Below is the script I used,

```
from selenium import webdriver

email, password = 'your-own-email', 'your-own-password'
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

driver.get("https://my.gumtree.com/login")
driver.find_element_by_name("username").send_keys(email)
driver.find_element_by_id("existingUser").click()
driver.find_element_by_id("fld-password").send_keys(password)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Continue')]").click()

driver.get("https://my.gumtree.com/postad")
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[text()='For Sale']")[-1].click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[text()[normalize-space()='Appliances']]").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[text()[normalize-space()='Home Appliances']]").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[text()[normalize-space()='Other Home Appliances']]").click()
```

For those elements that are not in view use the approach below,

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[text()[normalize-space()='Phones, Mobile Phones & Telecoms']]")
driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)
element.click()
```

Comment: No, it does not work I am afraid: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//span[text()[normalize-space()='Appliances']]"}

Comment: @Castle I added the script I used which is working for me. Note that the `implicitly_wait()` call might be important in this case as well!

Comment: Try `//li[contains(string(), 'Appliances')]`

Comment: @sowa It works with "//span[text()[normalize-space()='Appliances']]" but does not work with "//span[text()[normalize-space()='Phones, Mobile Phones &amp; Telecoms']]" or "//span[text()[normalize-space()='Phones, Mobile Phones & Telecoms']]". I am amazed how fragile Selenium is. Do you know how to make that work?

Comment: @Castle I updated my answer showing how to deal with those elements that are not in view.

Comment: @Castle Also, note that it is not Selenium being fragile here. Selenium simulates an end-user using the browser. An end-user cannot click on a link if that link is not in view, hence Selenium cannot either.

Answer (score 0):

If you have fixed strings in your HTML code, there is no need to use `contains()` method in xpath. Please use `text()` method of xpath:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(.//*[text()='Appliances'])).click();
```

The reason to use this is, if your HTML code contains two or more elements with the word "Applicances", it would not select any element. So, in order to avoid that ambiguity we can use `text()=` directly.

Hope this helps.

Comment: No, it does not work I am afraid: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//*[text()='Appliances']"}

Answer (score 0):

This kind of *contains* in XPath can be used in advanced scenarios, like your:

```
//span[text()[contains(.,'Appliances')]]
```

**@Edit:**

You can test all the XPath responses in this topic in Google Chrome using `$x("selector")`. Maybe the problem is in your selenium version.

I really don't know the python syntax (I used to create tests in C#), but you can do a ugly code that will work. Try to change the code to python, I think there are some errors:

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_cssselector("span.category-name")

for element in elements:
    if (element.text == "Appliances" || element.text == "Home Appliances" || element.text == "Other Home Appliances")
        element.click()
```

Comment: No, it does not work I am afraid: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//span[text()[contains(.,'Appliances')]]"}

Comment: @Castle now there is a code example using python to work. I think there is some error in syntax because I am not used to program in this language. Try it